# Assignment to an item of a list in single line for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variable-assignment

I want to make an assignment to an item of a list in a single line for loop.

First i have a list, where each list items are dictionary object. Then, i do for loop over each item of the list and compare if 'nodeid' field of dictionary is 106. If yes, i add new field to that dictionary. Code is below.

```
K= []
K.append({'nodeid': 100 ,'elemid': 200})
K.append({'nodeid': 106 ,'elemid': 206})
K.append({'nodeid': 107 ,'elemid': 206})
for item in K: 
   if item['nodeid']==106: 
     item['S']= [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]
```

I want to write loop part of the algorithm in a single line similiar as

```
[item['S']=12343 for item in K if item['nodeid']==106]
```

but this method does not work. 
How can i write this loop in a single line?

thanks

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine for this task. There is no need to try and write a one-liner other than practicing comprehensions.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using a list, you could have a dictionary of dictionaries, keyed by nodeid. Then you can easily do `K[106]['S'] = [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]`. In O(1) time, no less.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments writing a one-liner for this task is not the way to go as the amount of readability you lose is *massive*.

**But**, if driven out of pure curiosity, you could do it this way:

```
K = [x if x['nodeid'] != 106 else dict(x, **{'S': [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]}) for x in K]
```

the *magic* here happens with `dict(x, **{'S': [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]})` which essentially adds the two `dict`ionaries together and returns their result.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5+

```
K = [{**d, 'S': [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]} if d['nodeid'] == 106 else d for d in K]
```

Comment: this is more elegant than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do it that way if you wanted, like so:

```
K = []
K.append({'nodeid': 100 ,'elemid': 200})
K.append({'nodeid': 106 ,'elemid': 206})
K.append({'nodeid': 107 ,'elemid': 206})

K = [item if item['nodeid'] != 106 else dict(S=[2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35], **item) for item in K]
```

The `**` is Python's version of an "explode" or unpacking operator, used on a dictionary, described in detail [over here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131403).

---

*However*, it looks like your data wants to be in a dictionary already, considering the `nodeid`, so why not restructure it like that?

```
K = {}
K[100] = {'elemid': 200}
K[106] = {'elemid': 206}
K[107] = {'elemid': 206}

K[106]['S'] = [2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35]
```

This is the benefit of using hash/table data structures: fast and convenient (not to mention, readable) indexing. The location of every element is already known and you don't need to do any sort of iteration over the contained elements unless you have a secondary key criteria.

In addition, by using dictionaries, you avoid the cost of reconstructing the entire list, which happens through the use of the list comprehension in the first example given. Note however that you would not have that problem if you used the `for` loop which you began with, as that would only alter the element once found, and if you `break` after completing your operations, the loop would finish without incurring any additional costs.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of items, writing a one-liner means rebuilding the whole list, which isn't really efficient if you have sparse values to change.

In one-line (works with all versions of python >= 2.7):

```
K = [d if d['nodeid']!=106 else {k:v for k,v in list(d.items())+[('S',[2 , 124, 123 , 3532, 35])]} for d in K]
```

if the id doesn't match, issue the sublist, else build a dictionary with the sublist + the extra element (not using the fancy "dictionary additions" that all python versions don't have)